# ¿Como mostrar datos en un modal usando solo thymeleaf (proyecto SpringBoot MVC)?

Tags: bootstrap, mvc, spring-boot, modal

Sigo aprendiendo en Springboot y ahora me tope con otro problema que no entiendo en que estoy errando. No logro mostrar datos en un modal.

El html principal es este, (dentro de la Carpeta "Socio" esta este html con nombre "Club"):

```
    <body class="bg-info bg-opacity-25">
        <header th:replace="layout/plantilla :: header"></header>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../../static/openModals" th:src="@{/openModals.js}"></script>
        <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-header bg-primary bg-gradient">
                                <h4 class="text-light">Clubes Regisrados <i class="fa-solid fa-people-roof"></i></h4>
                            </div>
                                <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                                    <thead class="thead-dark">
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>#</th>
                                            <th th:text="nombre"></th>
                                            <th th:text="fechaFormacion"></th>
                                            <th th:text="vigente"></th>
                                            <th th:text="fechaCreate"></th>
                                            <th></th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr th:each="club : ${Clubs}">
                                            <td th:text="${club.getIdClub()}"></td>
                                            <td th:text="${club.getNombre()}"></td>
                                            <td th:text="${#dates.format(club.getFechaFormacion(), 'dd-MMM-yyyy')}"></td> 
                                            <td th:text="${club.getVigente()}"></td>
                                            <td th:text="${#dates.format(club.getFechaCreate(), 'dd-MMM-yyyy')}"></td> 
                                            <td class="d-grid gap-2 d-md-flex justify-content-md-end"> 
                                                <a th:href="@{/ver/Club/} + ${club.getIdClub}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm ms-1 text-white" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#verClub">
                                                    <i class="fa-solid fa-pen-to-square"></i> ver Club</a> 
                                                <a id="btnEditC" th:href="@{/get/Club/} + ${club.getIdClub}" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm ms-1 text-white">
                                                    <i class="fa-solid fa-pen-to-square"></i> editar club</a> 
                                                <a th:href="@{/delete/Club/} + ${club.getIdClub}" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm text-white">
                                                    <i class="fa-solid fa-trash-can"></i> eliminar club</a>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                                <section th:replace="Socio/forms/agregarClub :: editarClub"></section>
                                <section th:replace="Socio/forms/verClub :: verClub"></section>
                            <div class="alert alert-primary text-center p-2 fw-bolder align-self-center" role="alert" th:if="${Clubs == null or Clubs.empty}" style="width: 18rem;">
                                <span th:text="#{mensaje.lista-vacia}">Lista vacía</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <div class="card text-center">
                            <div class="card-header bg-success text-white">
                                <h3 >[[${TotalClubs}]] <i class="fa-solid fa-people-roof"></i></h3> 
                                <h3 class="fs-6"> total Registros </h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-body bg-info bg-opacity-25">
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#agregarClub">
                                    <i class="fas fa-plus"></i> agregar
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <section th:replace="Socio/forms/agregarClub :: agregarClub"></section>
                    </div>
                </div>
           </div>

        <footer th:replace="layout/plantilla :: footer"></footer>
    </body>
```

El controlador que se encarga de enviar los datos a mostrar del club seleccionado es:

```
    @GetMapping("/ver/Club/{id}")
public String ver(@PathVariable("id") int idClub, Model model){ //obtener para enviar al modal de edicion
    Club club = clubService.GetClub(idClub);
    model.addAttribute("Club", club);
    return "Socio/Club" ; 
}
```

Hasta acá todo funciona bien, excepto la opcion "ver club" que llama al modal verClub, el cuel es otro archivo html que esta referenciado desde el principal:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/extras/spring-security">
<head>
<title>Ver Club</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>

    <section th:fragment="verClub">
        <div class="modal fade" id="verClub" role="dialog"
            aria-labeledby="ModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header bg-success text-white">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="editarClublabel">
                            [[#{accion.ver}]] - [[${Club.getNombre()}]] <i class="fa-solid fa-people-roof"></i>
                        </h5>
                        <button class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal">
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="row gx-1 gy-3">
                            <div class="card col-4">
                                <div class="card-header">
                                    <h6 th:text="#{label.fechaCreate}"></h6>
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <p class="card-text fs-6" th:text="${Club.getFechaCreate()}">Fecha Creacion del Club</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card col-4">
                                <div class="card-header">
                                    <h6 th:text="#{label.nombre}"></h6>
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <p class="card-text fs-6" th:text="${Club.getNombre()}">Nombre del Club</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card col-4">
                                <div class="card-header">
                                    <h6 th:text="#{label.qrClub}"></h6>
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <p class="card-text fs-6" th:text="${Club.getQrClub()}">Codigo QR del Club</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card col-4">
                                <div class="card-header">
                                    <h6 th:text="#{label.fechaFormacion}"></h6>
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <p class="card-text fs-6" th:text="${Club.getFechaFormacion()}">fecha Formacion del club</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card col-4">
                                <div class="card-header">
                                    <h6 th:text="#{label.vigente}"></h6>
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <p class="card-text fs-6" th:text="${Club.getVigente()}">Indicador de Vigencia</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card col-4">
                                <div class="card-header">
                                    <h6 th:text="#{label.fechaDisolucion}"></h6>
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <p class="card-text fs-6" th:text="${Club.getFechaDisolucion()}"> fecha Disolucion del club</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card col-4">
                                <div class="card-header">
                                    <h6 th:text="#{label.mision}"></h6>
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <p class="card-text fs-6" th:text="${Club.getMision()}">mision del club</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card col-4">
                                <div class="card-header">
                                    <h6 th:text="#{label.vision}"></h6>
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <p class="card-text fs-6" th:text="${Club.getVision()}">vision del club</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card col-4">
                                <div class="card-header">
                                    <h6 th:text="#{label.imglogo}"></h6>
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-body">
                                     <img class="rounded mx-auto d-block"
                                        th:src="@{'/images/club/' + ${Club.getImglogo()}}"
                                        th:alt="${Club.getImglogo()}"
                                        style="max-width:70%;"> <!-- Muestra la imagen -->
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer bg-secondary bg-opacity-25">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">[[#{accion.ver}]] [[#{barra.socios}]]</button> 
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">[[#{accion.volver}]]</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

</body>
</html>
```

Se me muestra el modal, pero sin los datos enviados por el controlador. (por consola, veo que funciona todo)

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?